# Limit Django database table size and transfer data to another table

Tags: django, database, sqlite

So, I have a Django app which parses data from couple of websites (every 1-2 seconds it receives JSON array ~20-50 Kb) and writes it to default Django SQLite3 database table. For my purposes I need only 15-20 last records in this table and I'm afraid that it will be too large very soon because, for example, even after 24 hours it will be at least 800 Mb.

How can I make my app automatically transfer records that are older than last 15-20 to another table (let's call it archive table)?

Thank you!